# how to send a different texts to Multiple Contacts through single mailitem in outlook using C#?

Tags: c#, encryption, outlook, outlook-addin

i want to send a different content in multi contacts for a single mail item using c#.

Is this possible to achieve?
Ex:
TO:aaa@msoutlook.com,bb@msoutlook.com
Body:hi,how r u?
After i have click my custom button i want to send that body content as a encrypted text.each users have a different keys for encrypt.so after i have encrypted how to send that contents in different mailid.
i already tried to use `mailitem.send()`.but it send a single item only.

thanks
sanju

Comment: As you're sending different emails to different people (even if the original body-text is the same, encrypting with different keys makes the bodies different), so I'm pretty sure you'll just have to send separate emails: one to `aaa@msoutlook.com`; one to `bbb@msoutlook.com` etc.

Comment: In your Item_Send handler, you'll have to parse through the recipients and generate a new mail item for each of them, encrypt the body with the appropriate key, send each of those mail items, then finally cancel the original email (via the ref bool Cancel) param. Also - don't block the Item_Send event for too long or Outlook will stop raising it. Best to cancel the send, then use a queue or some other technique to process the request outside the handler.

Comment: Thanks for ur reply Chris.How to Cancel the item.send()?

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually have to send multiple mails. Instead cryptography standards such as PGP do it like this: Generate a random message key, encrypt your message with that message key, encrypt the message key with each recipient's key and put everything in your email. The overhead of the encrypted message keys for the other recipients will be minimal and independent of the message size.